# Using for loop to change column based different column changing all columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What am I missing?

In a Google Apps Script for a Google Sheet, the following code was suppose to go down column A and mark it "Test" when column C contained "Item Result". Instead it is changing all the cells in column C to "Item Result" and all the cells in Column A to "Test".

```
function changeName() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lRow = sh.getLastRow();
var data = sh.getRange(1, 1, lRow, 5).getValues();
var x;
for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
  if(data[i][2]='Item Result'){
  data[i][0]='Test';
  }
}
sh.getRange(1, 1, lRow, 5).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one "=" is true for not null value and means "assign value". that's why if statement in your case is always true and changes value. then it changes value in if block.
try "==" for if statement